# why my ViewController shrink in iOS 7.1 but work well in iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

http://ipeiwei.xyz/images/issue1.png

Why is it not complete? It works like a charm in iOS 8.3 on every device and iOS 7.1 on iPhone 4S, but with iOS 7.1 on larger devices (iphone 5, 6, 6+), it goes as shown in image.
I use storyboard and it inherits from UIViewcontroller; part of code is like:

```
    class AlumnusViewController: UIViewController {

        var tableView:UITableView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
            tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AlumniCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AlumniCell")
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            view.addSubview(tableView)
        }
}
```

I created a new Single View Application which runs in iOS 5S 7.1; the issue stays.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your app to display correctly on iPhone 5 & 6, you have to include appropriately-sized launch images or make use of a LaunchScreen.xib.

Comment: Why it relates to launch and LaunchScreen.xib?